# Converting a multiple-pdf to multiple images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, paperclip, ghostscript

i want to generate multiple images from one pdf.

Heres my logic:

```
has_attached_file :single_magazin,
                    :styles => {:for_magazine => ["768x1200>", :jpg], :preview => ["725x1200>", :jpg], :thumb => ["100x140>", :jpg] },
                    :processors => [:ghostscript, :thumbnail],

                    :convert_options => { :all => '-colorspace RGB -flatten -density 300 -quality 100' },

                    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename"



  validates_attachment_content_type :single_magazin,
                                    :content_type => [ 'application/pdf' ],
                                    :error => "only pdf files are allowed"
```

I want to upload a single PDF with multiple pages, and i want to output multiple jpg's. Each page to one JPG.

I'm using Rails 4.

I installed ghostscript and ImageMagick.

Please help me.

Markus

Comment: Duplicated. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503735/convert-pdf-to-image-as-per-the-pdf-page/

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to not use ImageMagick, but use GS directly, I don;t think ImageMagick exposes the GS interface enough to do this.

In Ghostscript set -sOutputFile=filename%d.extent and it will write one output file per page of the input.